# Chrome window.screenX set to zero at the wrong place

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, coordinates

```js
function f(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(
        ()=>{
            document.body.innerHTML = "X: "+window.screenX+"<br>Y: "+window.screenY;
            f();
        }
    );
};
f();
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, the X coordinate is set to zero at the wrong place, since the webbrowser is not stick to the left side of the screen. In fact, when the webbrowser is stick to the left, the X coordinate is negative:

[image]

My question is: How can I get the correct coordinates in spite of this in a reliable way? Is it ok to check if the webbrowser is Chrome and hardcode an offset to make sure the X coordinate is correct? Isn't there a better way? Am I getting the X coordinate the wrong way?

Comment: Are you on Windows?
My exact version of Chrome is Version 83.0.4103.106

Comment: `screenX` value is calculated based on the top window, (in Windows) it includes the  outer border of the chrome window, which you can set invisible, but it is still taken into account when calculating the window corner coordinates. All browsers are giving this same value for screenX.

Comment: @Teemu If I am having this issue I guess I have the outer border set invisible, but I don't remember doing so. Could you please tell me how to set it visible again?
If by invisible border you mean this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCJI1.jpg then it's not the problem.

Comment: I've set the invisible borders to windows a couple of years ago, but happily forgotten how = ). Click right mouse button on the desktop, the last contextmenu item (Customize) is probably where you should start.

Comment: Also if you have a second monitor placed upper-left of the main, then X Y will be negative when browser maximized on second monitor.

Comment: In Windows 11, the default is invisible borders.

Answer (score 0):

Windows/Microsoft decided, instead of eliminating the border entirely, they'd simply hide it by default (in Windows 11).

You can find the border settings under `Registry Editor` > `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`

The two things to change are:

- **BorderWidth**
- **PaddedBorderWidth**

The values of these are "twips". You'll have to 0 them both to eliminate the border.

From what it sounds like, you'll need to instead compensate programmatically for users likely having this on by default and not wanting to go through the effort of disabling it.